# Sonarqube generating unknown symbol messages

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are using Sonarqube 6.2 across two projects and several branches per project.  It has been working fine until today.

I have started seeing the following sorts of problems that I never saw before:

1.) Rule complaining about our Exception classes complaining that the class name should not end in Exception because they are not exceptions.  However, these classes are exceptions and they do extend Exception--they just do so through another common Exception class.

2.) I am starting to see false positives recommending that I delete an unused private method even though the method is being used!

3.) I am starting to get issues with messages that contain '!unknownSymbol!' in them.  For example:

Remove the redundant '!unknownSymbol!' thrown exception declaration(s).

It is flagging an Exception class that is not redundant and definitely is thrown from within the method.

I am using the Sonar Maven Plugin 3.2 to run the scans and push to the server.  Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you (or somebody else) recently upgraded the plugins that are installed on your SonarQube instance? This is probably the reason why you get new issues that you did not get before.

Comment: Not to my knowledge...

Comment: I'm getting issue 3 as well.. Have you figured out this?

Comment: I ended up moving to the latest LTS version of Sonarqube and the problems went away...